# Cannot print out max value from records in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
THE_TABLE:
Fname   |  Lname  |  Value   |  Date
John        Doe       200        20
John        Doe       300        21
John        Blah      200        19
John        Blah      400        21

select Fname,Lname,max(value) from THE_TABLE group by Fname,Lname;
```

This still prints out everything instead of:

```
John        Doe       300        21
John        Blah      400        21
```

How can I get it to print out the records with the max value depending on Fname and Lname?

Edit: is it possible to include a max in the where statement? so for example: `where value=max(value)`

Comment: You query is correct. You sure the value stored in value column is of numeric data type and not string. Also you cant use max in where clause. For that you can use HAVING.

Comment: Oh, would max work on a datetime value also?

Comment: And with or without the max, it returns the same number of rows

Comment: Yes it works with datetime values also.

Comment: Your query is working well. Its strange. Check my example below. Its the same query and I am getting the expected results.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the records with group-wise maximum values, then you have to do more work.  One way is to calculate the maximum per group and then join the results in.  There is another approach that doesn't use `group by` and can better take advantage of indexes.  This uses `not exists`:

```
select tt.*
from the_table tt
where not exists (select 1
                  from the_table tt2
                  where tt2.fname = tt.fname and tt2.lname = tt.lname and
                        tt2.value > t.value
                 );
```

This works because the maximum value for each name has a nice property.  No other values with the same name are bigger.  This query can take advantage of an index on `the_table(fname, lname, value)`;

Answer (score 0):

You're query is working perfectly fine. Here's a experiment that I did :

```
drop table abc;

create table abc as 
select 'ab' fname,'b' lname,100 value
union
select 'ab','b',200
union
select 'cb','c',500
union
select 'cb','c',600;

select fname, lname, max(value) from abc group by fname,lname;

-- RESULT
=============
 fname      lname     max(value)
 ab         b         200
 cb         c         600
```

Please check your table and its data types.